# Is there any selenium version (3.8.1) compatible with firefox latest versions?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Until now I tried 3.4.1 with firefox 53.0 and gecko driver 0.16. Curious if someone has tried latest webdriver version against any latest firefox versions?

Comment: You are mixing up 2 things. Current `Selenium` version is ***v3.8.1* where as `WebDriver` variant versions are different e.g. `GeckoDriver v0.19.1`. What is your exact question?

Comment: @DebanjanB I am talking about Selenium Client 3.8.1 which released on 2017-12-01

Answer (score -1):

The latest gecko driver (i.e v0.19.1) supports Firefox 54 and greater 
[(Refer here)](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/compare/v0.19.1...master)

Selenium version should be 3.5 and greater.[(Refer here)](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver)